# Which blocks will mobs walk off of voluntarily?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In version 1.10.x, what blocks will mobs voluntarily walk off of, thinking that they are solid blocks?

Answer (score 1):

There are few blocks that they (I tested with Zombies lead to Villagers and a 2-block wide pit) will think that are full and aren't. Their AI also makes them not go where they think there isn't a route - that is, even if they could fall off some other types of blocks, their AI won't drive them that way.

Here are some blocks that they count as full-solid:

- Trapdoors (both kinds)
- Doors (All kinds)

I couldn't find more, no matter what I tried - from Signs through Brewing Stands to Stairs. Nothing more, I guess. On the other hand, watch out for blocks that are solid, but mobs think not - Carpets, Heads, ...